# Understanding bind function

Tags: c, swift, haskell, functional-programming, monads

In this [article](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html), the author explains monad using this example (I am guessing Haskell is used):

> bind f' :: (Float,String) -> (Float,String)
>
> which implies that
>
> bind :: (Float -> (Float,String)) -> ((Float,String) ->
>   (Float,String))

and proceed to ask to implement the function bind and offer the solution as:

```
bind f' (gx,gs) = let (fx,fs) = f' gx in (fx,gs++fs)
```

I am having problem understanding the solution. What would this look like in C or Swift?

I have gone as far as I can implementing the example and I am stuck at implementing bind:

```
let f: Float -> Float = { value in return 2 * value }
let g: Float -> Float = { value in return 10 + value }

let ff: Float -> (Float, String) = { value in return (f(value), "f called") }
let gg: Float -> (Float, String) = { value in return (g(value), "f called") }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ I think it would look something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using P = std::pair<float, std::string>;
using FP = std::function<P(P)>;

FP mbind(std::function<P(float)> f) {
    return [f](P in) {
        auto && res = f(in.first);
        return {res.first, in.second + res.second};
    };
}
```

In C you could do something similar by storing function pointers, though the invocation syntax would have to be more verbose since you'll need to pass the state around explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, perhaps something like this:

```
let bind: (Float -> (Float, String)) -> ((Float, String) -> (Float, String)) = { 
    lhs in

    return { 
        rhs in

        let result = lhs(rhs.0)
        return (result.0, "\(result.1); \(rhs.1)" )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a `bind` for Writer monad. The `bind` function for that monad should do 2 things:

1. Execute computation with `Float` value.
2. Update the existing log (a `String` value).

Initially you have a tuple `(oldFloat,oldString)` and want to apply to this tuple a function with type `Float -> (Float,String)`.

Your function takes an `oldFloat` value from tuple `(oldFloat,oldString)` and returns a tuple `(newFloat,newString)`.

What behavior do you expect from your `bind` function? I suppose you want to get a tuple containing a `newFloat` and updated log `oldString ++ new string`, right? Here is a straitforward implementation of it:

```
bind f (oldFloat,oldString) =
    -- apply function f to oldFloat from tuple (oldFloat,oldString) 
    -- to get a new tuple (newFloat,newString)
    let (newFloat,newString) = f oldFloat
    -- you want from your bind function to get a tuple containing 
    -- a newFloat and a newString added to oldString
    in (newFloat, oldString ++ newString)
```

Comment: Yes, the behavior you said is right.  However, I am not sure from the article whether bind should take one argument or two.  Given that it's Haskell, I assume it has to be one argument, but not sure how bind should be called.

Comment: `bind` always takes two arguments: the initial value `(oldFloat,oldString)` and the function `oldFloat -> (newFloat,newString)`